# why json response has square brackets

Tags: javascript, php, json

For some reason I have to use JSON like this:

php code

```
$json = json_decode([{
"key":1812,
        "ticks":0,
        "events":"7F7E7F7E7F7E7F7E7F7E7F7E7F7E",
        "s1a":"011A00002066C0D9",
        "s1c":"011C0149040901496650002830000000000000023344000043410000000300000004C5BD",
        "s46":"014600283000CA8D","s10":"011000287182943B",
        "s9a":"019A0000000018000000000000000000DC69",
        "version" : "18.05" 
}]);

// and use $json in loop to populate the table...
```

that pair of square brackets does not let me do anything with it in php. My editor show an parse error. I solved this problem in js like this:

```
var data = json[0];
var i;
for(i=0; i<json.length; i++){
    var html = '';
    html += '<td>' + json[i]["key"] + '</td>'
    + '<td>' + json[i]["ticks"] + '</td>'
    + '<td>' + json[i]["events"] + '</td>'
    + '<td>' + json[i]["s1a"] + '</td>'
    + '<td>' + json[i]["s1c"] + '</td>'
    + '<td>' + json[i]["s46"] + '</td>'
    + '<td>' + json[i]["s9a"] + '</td>'
    + '<td>' + json[i]["version"] + '</td>';
}
    $(html).appendTo('#bundle');
//var jsonEncoded = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(json.length);*/
```

But it seems bad to use it like this. How can I solve this in php?

Comment: Do you mean the `[` and `]`? That's how you write an array in JSON.

Comment: The same way you (hopefully) did in JS: `thatJSONData[0]->key` and so on

Comment: yes thats them but how does can use that in php it always shows parse error?

Comment: Show us the php code. Nobody is going to guess what you are doing with it. See [mcve]

Comment: @LucaKiebel I did it as you say. But is there way to use it directly in php? Or I am missing a lot...

Comment: Angle brackets = `<>`. Square brackets = `[]`. Curly braces = `{}`

Comment: @Barmar thanks for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply use `json_decode` for this in PHP, Like:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode($json);
var_dump($data[0]->key);
var_dump($data[0]->events);
```

And you can access them simply by using the index `0`. [Demo](https://eval.in/913800)

**Edit:** The problem with your code is that your are not enclosing the json string in quotations. You should use it like this:

```
$json = json_decode('[{
"key":1812,
        "ticks":0,
        "events":"7F7E7F7E7F7E7F7E7F7E7F7E7F7E",
        "s1a":"011A00002066C0D9",
        "s1c":"011C0149040901496650002830000000000000023344000043410000000300000004C5BD",
        "s46":"014600283000CA8D","s10":"011000287182943B",
        "s9a":"019A0000000018000000000000000000DC69",
        "version" : "18.05" 
}]');
```

Comment: This seems very logical. And I tried that. For some reason I had in this example to use that json not as php variable but in its original shape. As is shown in edit.

Comment: @ZeljkoMiloradovic You can use it directly instead of via variable, but you must enclose it in quotations, always.

Comment: can you privide example please? @mega

Comment: @ZeljkoMiloradovic You can see it in my answer, look at the last code. After **Edit**

Comment: I am slow... Thanks it really works! I tried with double quotes, but it doesnt work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Also worth mentioning that if you are using an ORM, and you are working with collections (which is a common use case with Laravel, for example, and with many other PHP frameworks), there are two ways you can return something that you are looking for in a query.

First: you query an array of elements, and in this case, only one is found. Then, if you pass that as your response, it will contain the array brackets - a valid JSON type.

But if you specifically query for a single element (like with ::first() in the case of Eloquent), if you return that, it will automatically only return the object, without any enclosing brackets.

Edit: seeing your edit, yeah, mega6382 has the answer.